# MailChimp API listStaticSegments is always empty

Tags: php, api, mailchimp

I have created several static Segments in Mailchimp for a List.
I am writing some PHP to create campaigns, but I am stuck on a hurdle early on.

I am using v1.3 of the MailChimp API

```
$api = new MCAPI( $this->config['api_key'] );
$lists = $api->listStaticSegments( $list_id );

var_dump( $api );
var_dump( $lists );
```

Results:

```
object(MCAPI)[39]
public 'version' => string '1.3' (length=3)
public 'errorMessage' => string '' (length=0)
public 'errorCode' => string '' (length=0)
public 'apiUrl' => 
  array (size=4)
    'scheme' => string 'http' (length=4)
    'host' => string 'api.mailchimp.com' (length=17)
    'path' => string '/1.3/' (length=5)
      'query' => string 'output=php' (length=10)
  public 'timeout' => int 300
  public 'chunkSize' => int 8192
  public 'api_key' => string 'XXX' (length=XX)
  public 'secure' => boolean false

  array (size=0)
  empty
```

I am expecting `$lists` to have 10 items in an array. 
When I log into MailChimp and check the API Account API Keys page, I can see there are requests but there are no responses.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ha. The problem was I had no static lists. The lists that I had created were dynamic segments (auto updating) , so therefore I must use `campaignSegmentTest` to generate the same criteria for the dynamic segments.

http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/campaignsegmenttest.func.php

Further research on the Google Mailchimp forum:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mailchimp-api-discuss/63DLfYq7ydI/jyGASmUxK8AJ